# RxJava transforming Single with collection

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

Given following `Single` of `Set` with String values

```
    Single<Set<String>> sss = Single.just(Sets.newHashSet("1" , "2", "3"));
```

I would like to transform this to  `Single<Set<Integer>>` that should contain elements transformed to Integers. Let's assume transformation from String to Integer is very costly and each element should be transformed **in parallel**. How to achieve this?

I tried transforming it to `Observable`, but couldn't merge it back to `Single`:

```
    Single<Set<Integer>> ssi = sss.toObservable()
        .flatMapIterable(e -> e)
        .map(Integer::parseInt)
        .join()//??
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the parallel extensions:

```
Single<Set<String>> sss = Single.just(Sets.newHashSet("1" , "2", "3"));

Single<Set<Integer>> ssi = sss
    .flattenAsFlowable(e -> e)
    .parallel()
    .runOn(Schedulers.computation())
    .map(Integer::parseInt)
    .sequential()
    .toList(HashSet::new);
```